# how to get facebook game request url?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, facebook-app-requests

we are using facebook unity sdk game requests on android.

- when someone clicks a game request in their facebook notifications
- they switch to the game or the app store page (if it's not installed)
- when the game runs, we call FB.GetAppLink(DeepLinkCallback)
- however, we receive empty url.

anyone knows how to achieve this ?

Thanks.

Full code:

```
 void AfterInit(){
         FB.GetAppLink(DeepLinkCallback);
     }

     void DeepLinkCallback(IAppLinkResult result) {
         Debug.Log("app url = "+result.Url);
     }
```

Comment: anyone knows what's the issue ?

Comment: (deep linking is enabled in facebook dashboard)

Answer (score 0):

Update: 
Sorry For posting the same code. I have a question for you.

Is your app life in the store and linked to Facebook developer profile correctly? If is in test mode it can fail.

However I believe that the ID you need to send in-app invites is the app ID from Facebook developer profile.
(check the image)

[Facebook developer profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35RRR.png)

the example code for the in-app invites is this

```
FB.Mobile.AppInvite(
    new Uri("https: // fb. me/810530068992919"), //the ID
    new Uri("http://i.imgur.com/zkYlB.jpg"), // optional image
    AppInviteCallback //callback function
);
```

Hope that this can solve your issues.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, it is not different from the code i've posted in the question, for some reason, i was not getting any url ( i think it was empty or null (can't remember since i asked the question 3 months ago)

Comment: the issue was not solved, & i've cut this feature as i couldn't solve it at that time , however, when i tested , the app was not live on the store.
Thanks.

Comment: I think that this info is what you need: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios#app_links

Let me know if that works. I have the appinvites working on my app, so I don't understand why that doesn't work.

Thanks!